# Building an ActiveRecord query from a distant association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If a `Diary` has many `Page`s,

and each `Page` has many `LoveLetter`s,

and the `LoveLetter`s have many `Recipients` through `Relationships`,

then using ActiveRecord, how might I select all `Page`s who have `LoveLetter`s that have `Recipient`s (through `Relationship`s) of `name == "Bob"`?

I tried using `where`, but it makes me specify a foreign key after a certain amount of nested associations, and I can't query the model any more:

```
diary = Diary.take
diary.pages.where(love_letters: { recipient_id #... 
# I can't put 'recipient' here and keep nesting hashes, apparently.
# I think I have to specify the column name.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but off the top of my head:

```
 Page.joins(:love_letters).merge(LoveLetter.joins(:recipients)).merge(Recipient.where(:name => "Bob"))
```

If that doesn't work, try it with Relationships merged also.

```
Page.joins(:love_letters).merge(LoveLetter.joins(:recipients)).merge(Relationship.merge(:recipients)).merge(Recipient.where(:name => "Bob"))
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked for me. To other who stumble upon this -- a better way of structuring these model associations probably exists, but this question was just for the sake of example. The pattern that worked for me was CollectionA.joins(:collection_b).merge(CollectionB.joins(:collection_c)).merge ........ .merge(CollectionN.where(:attribute => "Attribute Value"))